# Why EPSILON is used in comparing two floating point numbers

Tags: java, math, floating-point, epsilon

I'm googling about how to find if a number `y` is power of `x` and came across this [link](https://leetcode.com/articles/power-of-three/)

> **Java**
>
> ```
> public class Solution {
> public boolean isPowerOfThree(int n) {
>     return (Math.log10(n) / Math.log10(3)) % 1 == 0;
> } }
> ```
>
> **Common pitfalls**
>
> This solution is problematic because we start using doubles, which
>   means we are subject to precision errors. This means, we should never
>   use `==` when comparing doubles. That is because the result of
>   `Math.log10(n) / Math.log10(3)` could be `5.0000001` or `4.9999999`. This
>   effect can be observed by using the function `Math.log()` instead of
>   `Math.log10()`.
>
> In order to fix that, we need to compare the result against an
>   `epsilon`.
>
> **Java**
>
> `return (Math.log(n) / Math.log(3) + epsilon) % 1 <= 2 * epsilon;`

There I didn't understand `return (Math.log(n) / Math.log(3) + epsilon) % 1 <= 2 * epsilon;`

What is the meaning of that line?

Why **`EPSILON`** is used while comparing floating points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the quoted section says, because of floating point imprecisions, you can have two numbers that should be exactly equal (if the calculations that created them were carried out with mathematical exactness), but that are instead slightly different.

When you compare them, you want to account for that slight difference and still treat numbers as equal if they differ only by a small amount, called epsilon.

How to choose an appropriate epsilon, though, is a tricky question and highly dependent on the nature of your calculations. I suppose that for this reason, Java does not include a "standard" epsilon constant (some other languages do).

Comment: So, can I do `i = Math.log(n)/Math.log(3);` and `return i - floor(i) < EPSILON `? Or is there any reason for adding `EPSILON` and `%1` on the left-hand and `2*EPSILON` on the right-hand side in the question?

Comment: Using `%1` does seems a bit weird. I don't think it would work at all if the numbers are totally different (`25.001 % 1 = 0.001`) or not in the right order (`0.999999 %1 = 0.999999`).

Comment: So EPSILON is just a number we are using to check the error upto certain number. Like `0.001` if we want the precision to be upto 3 digits. Right?

Comment: @unknownymouse: Yes, more or less, although with a precision up to 3 digits I would still use a (much) smaller epsilon, just to be sure that not too many different values are considered equal.Epsilon should be chosen not too far from the possible error, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Because natural logarithm calculates using simple series. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm
Such series may be implemented in math-coprocessor in CPU. You may express any logarithm from natural using simple proportion without big computation time.